# C++.NET, Link can't find file Debug/.obj (notice strange file name)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

**I have added some information to this question, below the line of xxxx.**

I am attempting to move a large ActiveX (legacy) control from Visual C++ version 6 to Visual Studio 2010.  The build went just fine under VSC++6.  The automated conversion (within VS2010) seemed to run smoothly.  There were a number of minor errors which had to be corrected in the code, such as having to declare variables to be integer rather than letting them default.  Upon fixing the last error and building, the link step gave this error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '.\Debug\/.obj'
```

I have searched and found a couple people had asked about this problem, but the solutions were very project specific.  I could find nothing that applied to my situation.

There were two projects in the original solution.  To attempt to solve the problem, I separated them into two separate solutions, one of which produces a .dll and works and the other (to produce the activeX component) which fails with the above error.

I really don't know where to look.

I have no .cpp nor .h files with Debug in the filename.

There must be something telling the linker to look for this file... but where?  How would I even recognize it.  (I'm not even sure what the forward slash in the filename represents.  Is it escaping the period... or does the pair of characters (backslash forwardslash, \ /) escape the forward slash meaning it is part of the filename?)

Where do I even start?

I think that I have heard that Visual Studio generates command lines which actually do the compilation and linking.  **Is there any way to see the generated command line to do the Link?**

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I just located 3 files with names and content as shown.  They seem to be
related to the problem.  The 3rd file shows the bad file name (twice).  Can anyone tell me where in the Visual Studio GUI they are set up?  Or what may cause the erroneous entries in the last file?

```
custombuild.command.1.tlog -------------------
^C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\QGETL32.ASM
..\Assembler\ml /Fo.\Debug\Qgetl32.obj /coff /I. /Zi /c /Cx /Ta Qgetl32.asm
^C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\ROT32.ASM
..\Assembler\ml /Fo.\Debug\Rot32.obj /coff /I. /Zi /c /Cx /Ta Rot32.asm
custombuild.read.1.tlog ----------------------
^C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\QGETL32.ASM
^C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\ROT32.ASM
custombuild.write.1.tlog ---------------------
^C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\QGETL32.ASM
C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\DEBUG\.OBJ
^C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\ROT32.ASM
C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\USER1\DESKTOP\QUILT00\DEBUG\.OBJ
```

Comment: This is dredging up ancient memories of upgrading VC6 projects to run in new versions. I think a number of settings get screwed up, including the  output filenames (just reset them to the default, usually) and/or the linker inputs and maybe a handful of others. The "Debug" in the filename is coming from the configuration name (Debug, Release, any custom configurations), not a source file name. The mixed backslashes are due to how it tries to construct paths, not escape codes. Some places in the IDE use \, others /.

Comment: Right, it is very project specific.  We can't see your .vcxproj file.